# hiding table view and in same time showing the search bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, searchbar

In my app i have a table view and a search bar on it .Can i anyonme tell me the way to hide the table view initially and show the search bar and also when i click on the search bar then only table vie wshould be displayed .Please provide some answers.

Thanks ,
Christy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every view has a `hidden` property. Whenever u want to hide the table just do `[tableView setHidden:YES]`. As for showing the tableView whenever the searchBar is clicked, set its delegate to self (or any class in which you are implementing the `UISearchBarDelegate`) and in the method `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` just do [tableView setHidden:NO]. Hope it helps.